# angular filter on array of strings in controller

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller

Is it possible to filter on an array of strings rather than just one string as per https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter?

```
$scope.data = [
{
    name: 'tim',
    age: 21
},
{
    name: 'mike',
    age: 11
},
{
    name: 'jack',
    age: 61
},
{
    name: 'bob',
    age: 31
},
{
    name: 'kate',
    age: 96
},              
];

$scope.arrayOfStrings = ['mike', 'bob', 'tim'];

$filter('customFilter')($scope.data, $scope.arrayOfStrings);
```

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.filter()` or a comparator function in `$filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  Here is a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/e8yLSV3AwskKlscIPYvp?p=preview

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
  .filter('customFilter', customFilter);

  function customFilter () {
    return function (input, arrayOfString) {
      return input.filter( function( el ) {
        return arrayOfString.indexOf( el.name ) < 0;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes sure, why not? You can do something like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule', [])
.filter('filterFromArray', function() {
  return function(input, arrayToMatch) {
    input = input || [];
    arrayToMatch= arrayToMatch|| [];
    var l = input.length,
        k = arrayToMatch.length,
        out = [], i = 0,
        map = {};

    for (; i < k; i++) {
      map[arrayToMatch[k]] = true;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if(map[input[i].name]){
          out.push(input[i]);
      }
    }

    return out;
  };
});
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
$filter('filterFromArray')($scope.data, $scope.arrayOfStrings);
```

or in a expression:

```
{{ data | filterFromArray:arrayOfStrings}}
```

You can also add more parameters to even match aq particular field in an object, not just the name, but that is up to you.